# What's the number of irreducible polynomials over rational numbers with constraint on coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, fields

Suppose you have polynomials $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ where $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $a_k$ can be either $0$ or $1$. There are $2^n$ such polynomials in total. How can I find a number of irreducible polynomials among them?

I know there is an exact formula for the case $f \in F_q[x]$ where $F_q$ is a finite field. Is there a similar result for $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and mentioned constraints for $a_k$?

Comment: There is no formula for the number of such polynomials.  We do have asymptotic results for the number of such polynomials. See for example  the paper of Breuillard and Varju here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.13360.pdf which is conditional on GRH  and gives that almost all of $2^{n-1}$ polynomials with $a_0\neq 0$ and the paper here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.14567.pdf which gives a positive proportion of these polynomials are irreducible. Getting a precise count is definitely impossible.

Comment: Do you fix $a_n=1$? If so, the counts are given in https://oeis.org/A087482

Comment: @VladMatei Thanks!

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev yes, it's a sane proposition.